# unable to capture ImageButton click in postback event

Tags: asp.net

Unable to capture the Imagebuttonclick event in postback.

I am using the below code for Button click and tried for Imagebutton as well however "Button" click its working and not for Image button.

```
public Control GetPostBackControl(Page page)
    {
        Control control = null;

        string ctrlname = page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
        if ((ctrlname != null) & ctrlname != string.Empty)
        {
            control = page.FindControl(ctrlname);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (string ctl in page.Request.Form)
            {
                Control c = page.FindControl(ctl);
                if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)
                {
                    control = c;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return control;
    }
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution:

Added one more check in the above mentioned code,
     // handle the ImageButton postbacks

```
        if (control == null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < page.Request.Form.Count; i++)
            {

                if ((page.Request.Form.Keys[i].EndsWith(".x")) || (page.Request.Form.Keys[i].EndsWith(".y")))
                {
                    control = page.FindControl(page.Request.Form.Keys[i].Substring(0, page.Request.Form.Keys[i].Length - 2));                     
                }
            }
        }
```

And now I am able to capture the ImageButton postback event.

Thanks

Comment: where did you add this check? Could you post your full code?

Answer (score 0):

try using replacing your button check block with this:

```
if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton)
            {
                control = c;
                break;
            }
```

Comment: this will not work as the Button and Imagebutton click event process are different. I got the solution already and posted the same.